# How to patch a JSON in Cloud Firestore in android?

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to patch a collection in firestore as and when the value needs to be updates but it needs to be done using REST api in android.
POST does not work in firestore

I am not able to find any proper documentation to follow.

The structure is
Integer.valueOf(data.getFields().getOptions().getMapValue().getFields().getOption().getIntegerValue());
where X ranges from 1 to 5
example : .getOption1().getIntegerValue();
I am fetching the json, updating option field as and when it is clicked
but I dont know how to send data back to firestore

Not getting any response.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to send your updated value as a GET parameter?

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()

.scheme("http")
.authority("example.com")
.path("someurl")
.appendQueryParameter("param1", foo)
.appendQueryParameter("param2", bar)
.build();
```

Regards